# querySelectorAll that only returns id names

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I'm try to querySelector all the divs in that day and return the ID names. The only problem is that
Every time i try it. It will return one of the following things |
it also returns the P | it shows the full HTML code. | It returns a error

Code exempel:

```
  <div id=Monday>
   <div id="MA_meeting1_8:30_10:00">
     <p>text<p>
     <p>SomeText<p>
   </div>
   <div id="MA_meeting2_10:30_11:00">
     <p>text<p>
     <p>SomeText<p>
   </div> 
  </div>
```

.

```
document.querySelector(X).id
```

it wil only return

```
MA_meeting1_8:30_10:00
```

And im try it to return it like:

```
MA_meeting1_8:30_10:00
MA_meeting2_10:30_11:00
```

Comment: What is `a`? Also note that `document.querySelector` returns the _first_ element - you're looking for `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the parent `div` with id `Monday` and then use `querySelectorAll`. This is give a collection so use spread syntax `...` to use array method `map` and return an array of the `ids`

```js
let k = [...document.getElementById('Monday').querySelectorAll('div')].map(item => item.id);
console.log(k)
```

```html
<div id='Monday'>
  <div id="MA_meeting1_8:30_10:00">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>SomeText
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="MA_meeting2_10:30_11:00">
    <p>text
    </p>
    <p>SomeText
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. Nice. That said - there is a slightly better selector you could use.  `let k = [...document.querySelectorAll('#Monday > div')].map(item => item.id);`

Comment: Not suggesting this should be part of the answer, but it annoys me that the language makes it easier to do inefficient things than efficient things. In this case `[...arrayLike].map(...)` makes a temporary array to get the final result which wastes memory and time, while `Array.prototype.map.call(arrayLike, ...)` acts directly on the array-like object to get the final result.